# MYSQL Update Query syntax issues

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, sql-update

I am currently attempting to update a specific record in my database however although I have checked the syntax thoroughly chrome is telling me that I have it wrong somewhere.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated

```
$title = $_POST["title"];
$alttext = $_POST["alttext"];
$description = $_POST["description"];
$price = $_POST["price"];
$id = $_POST["ID"];
$insertQuery = "UPDATE cmsproducts SET Title = '$title', Alt_Text = '$alttext', Source = '$target_path', Description = '$description', Price = $price WHERE ID = $id";

// Save the form data into the database 
if ($result = $connector->query($insertQuery)){

// It worked, give confirmation
echo '<center><b><span style="color: #FF0000;">Product added to the database</span></b></center><br /><br />';

}else{

// It hasn't worked so stop. Better error handling code would be good here!
echo('<center>Sorry, there was an error saving to the database</center>');
echo "<center><b>File Name:</b> ".$target_path."<br/>";
die(mysql_error());


}
```

I have tried the query without the variables to check if it was a problem there but it still screamed error at me:

Sorry, there was an error saving to the database
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'of test, Source=../images/Pictures/, Description=This is a test image of test ' at line 1

Comment: echo your $insertQuery variable and check the final query. Maybe something is empty or has any format/encoding issue, who knows (you're not checking the POST input by the way, it is a security issue).

Comment: We cannot help you, until you let us know what is being passed in the "post" variables, as well as what the DB schema looks like. Also you MUST protect against SQL Injection!!

Comment: This is also a security issue. You might want to use mysql_real_escape_string or other means in order to prevent sql injection attacks.

Comment: Write a description of `';delete from cmsproducts--`, I dare you!

Comment: Thank you all for your worries of SQL Injection =] I actually have validation checks running further up the page, it is just for the moment that it is without security checks. I will be adding the code after it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always escape user input (`mysql_real_escape_string`) or use PDO and assign parameters. It seems that `$alttext` variable has quote or other special character in it. For example,

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["title"]);
$alttext = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["alttext"]);
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["description"]);
$price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["price"]);
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["ID"]);
$insertQuery = "UPDATE cmsproducts SET Title = '$title', 
   Alt_Text = '$alttext', Source = '$target_path',
   Description = '$description', Price = '$price' WHERE ID = '$id'";
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're not escaping quotes as your column `Description` must have a single quote inside. Use `mysql_real_escape_string` to escape quotes.

Comment: After adding the mysql_real_escape_string and adding my validation checks I have come to the realisation I was uploading to the wrong site LOL I was uploading to the live test server rather than the no-access test server
It is always the simplest thing...